# Null Pointer Error with pre-allocated memory?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null-pointer

While doing a coding exercise in C, I had to allocate memory for a pointer to a structure (`cur`), even though the structure presumably already had memory pre-allocated for it, otherwise I would get an 'assignment to null pointer' type of error.

I was under the assumption that if the pointer was going to point to a structure with pre-allocated memory, allocating further memory would be reduntant? To clarify, the code compiles and runs without errors, just confused as to why I needed to allocate memory to achieve the intended behavior.

```
/* create a stack */
typedef struct {
    int top;
    struct TreeNode array[MAX_ARR_SIZE];
} Stack;

int node_comparator(const void *p, const void *q);

struct TreeNode *increasingBST(struct TreeNode *root) {
    /* add all the nodes to an array via DFT */
    int i, sorted_pos = 0;
    struct TreeNode *start, *cur;
    struct TreeNode sorted_nodes[MAX_ARR_SIZE];
    Stack *node_stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    
    node_stack->top = -1; 
    node_stack->array[++node_stack->top] = *root;
    
   /* below is the pointer in question 
    * originally, this line was not here */
    cur = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
    
    while (node_stack->top != -1) {
        /* "pop" node off stack */
        *cur = node_stack->array[node_stack->top--];
        
        /* add node to array */
        sorted_nodes[sorted_pos++] = *cur;
        
        /* add right and left node to stack, if present */
        if (cur->right != NULL)
            node_stack->array[++node_stack->top] = *cur->right;
        
        if (cur->left != NULL)
            node_stack->array[++node_stack->top] = *cur->left;
    }
/* etc... */
```

Here's a [link](https://gist.github.com/jose-marquez89/c14e8fb407e6a9f924dadaa26755f34b) to a gist for full context. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by ‘pre allocated memory’

Comment: In a leetcode.com exercise, a binary tree was created in a main function, presumably a solution file. The goal was to create a function that would return a rearranged, sorted tree head node. These nodes were presumably created before my function was called, thus already having memory allocated for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra memory isn't redundant since you want to save the node's details off the stack.  However, you don't need to use `malloc`.  You can declare `cur` at the top of your function (`struct TreeNode cur;`) and then use `memcpy` (from `string.h`).

```
memcpy(&cur,&node_stack->array[node_stack->top--],sizeof(cur));
```

Since `cur` is no longer a pointer, you would need to edit your code and replace occurrences of `cur->` with `cur.`.